# why couldn't airodump-ng change channel?

Tags: aircrack-ng

[image]

If I run airodump-ng on channel 10, why does it shows networks from channel 1? Why couldn't is change the CH?

The only way I can change the channel is that I try to connect to a channel 10 network with nm-applet... then again try airodump-ng, and only then it scans/shows in REALITY ch 10 networks.

Question: Why does it stays in a channel? Ex.: 1.. why cannot it switch and scan on the selected 10?

Comment: Have you ran 'airmon-ng check kill' or appended '--ignore-negative-one" tor your airmon an airodump command?

Comment: Please add your OS, the wireless card used and the chipset of that card.

Comment: You can work around this by issuing `iw dev wlan0 set channel CH` at runtime. At least this works on ath9k chips.

Comment: can you post this as answer? :) I will try it out later. Many thanks!